# Proof by Pairing Multiplicative Inverses

Tags: modular-arithmetic

- Pairing up multiplicative inverses, show that $(p − 1)! \equiv −1 \pmod p$ for prime $p$
- Show that if $N$ is not prime, then $(N-1)! \not \equiv −1 \pmod N$. (Can use $d = \gcd(N, (N − 1)!)$ )

I know that all numberers in $(p-1)!$ can be grouped into $\frac{p-1}{2}$ paris that is congruent to 1 mod p. By I'm not sure how to go about proving it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

I

Comment: The first question mentions "prime x", but it doesn't appear anywhere else - is "prime p" meant instead ?

Comment: Sorry it was typos. it suppose to be p.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem for the first question. For the second one , I think it is enough to have a counter example: we have $$ (9-1)!  \equiv 8!  \equiv 40320  \equiv 0  \;  (mod \; \; 9) $$

Comment: @Nizar: It is not enough to give a single example of a statement that should apply to ALL non-primes.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, remember that the modular equation $x^2\equiv 1\pmod p$ has solutions $x\equiv\pm1\pmod p$ when $p$ is a prime. So $p-1$ and $1$ are their own inverses modulo $p$. If $p=2$ we have $1=p-1$ and clearly $1!\equiv -1\pmod 2$. For $p\geq 3$, the other factors in $(p-1)!$ can be grouped into $\frac{p-3}2$ pairs of inverses and so $(p-1)!\equiv (p-1)\cdot 1^{(p-3)/2}\cdot 1\equiv-1\pmod p$.

On the other hand, if $N$ is composite, it must have at least one prime factor $p<N$ which then also divides $(N-1)!$. So if $(N-1)!=qN+r$ and $p$ divides both $N$ and $(N-1)!$, it must divide $r$ as well showing that $r=-1$ is simply impossible.

Finally the case $N=1$ should be considered too, but $(1-1)!=0!=1\equiv-1\pmod 1$, as Daniel Fischer rightfully pointed out. This suggests that the second statement should be "if $N$ is composite" rather than "if $N$ is not prime".

Comment: Actually, $1 \equiv -1 \pmod{1}$. In fact, $m \equiv n \pmod{1}$ for all $m,n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Indeed! I did not think it through properly, I am afraid. Thanks!